# How to find if an array contains a specific value in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if my list `.sidebar` contains `data-id="1"`.

```
<ul class="sidebar">
  <li data-id="1">Option 1</li>
  <li data-id="2"> Option 2</li>
  <li data-id="3"> Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $('.sidebar').each(function({}));

Comment: That isn't valid HTML. I doubt it's producing what you think it's producing.

Comment: update ur question with proper `html` and details

Comment: @JAG u sure, don't see any edit?

Comment: Assuming it was valid, as in  `<li data-id="1"></li>` you could do `$('.sidebar li[data-id="1"]').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all LI's with a `data-id` attribute with the value `1`, and check the length of the collection to see if that element exists

```
var exists = $('.sidebar li[data-id="1"]').le‌​ngth !== 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

`var hasIt = $('ul.sidebar[data-id="1"]').size() > 0;`